# This function does not properly handle non-NULL terminated strings

Tags: c, sonarqube, embedded, code-analysis

I ran a code analysis on my embedded C code with SonarCube with sonar.cxx plugin.

I also parse with sonarcube the XML generated with [Rough Auditing Tool for Security (RATS)](https://security.web.cern.ch/security/recommendations/en/codetools/rats.shtml) and i get this error:

> This function does not properly handle non-NULL terminated strings. This does not result in exploitable code, but can lead to access violations.

This is the code that generates the above error:

```
  if( (machineMarket == NULL) || (strlen(machineMarket) > VALUE_MARKET_MAX_LEN) )
```

Which is the best practise to handle the non NULL terminated string?

Comment: Use `strnlen()` instead of `strlen()`? Though I find it hard to believe that would completely solve the problem if there's a way to get non-NULL terminated strings to that code at all.

Comment: To be pedantic, an array of `char` that is not null-terminated is not a string in C. And for yet more pedantry, note that `NULL` is the null-pointer macro, while the null-terminator is `\0`, sometimes referred to as `NUL`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Still can lead to access violation in case the max length given is exceeding the readable memory. So I don't really see a way to avoid this by any means except of properly terminating the string. But perhaps it will silence the security audit tool

Comment: @EugeneSh. - I agree.  Using `strnlen()` just pushes the problem - and not even in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auditing tool is warning that the call to `strlen` will keep reading bytes until it finds a zero byte. If the contents of `machineMarket` do not contain a zero, it is possible that strlen will keep reading right off the end of legal memory and cause an access violation.

You say you are declaring the variable like this
 `char machineMarket[VALUE_MARKET_MAX_LEN + 1];`
So you can either use the `strnlen` function to ensure you never read too far, or use @Zan Lynx's method of forcibly inserting a 0 at the end.

With either method, you'll probably need to handle the case where the original string is/was not terminated.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I handle it is whenever I get a string from outside my module, from a network read or a call into my library, I set a 0 on the end of it. Now, no matter what, it is a valid C string.

So if my library function accepts `int func(char *output, size_t output_len)` then right up front before I use it for anything I always validate with `if( !output || !output_len) return;` and then `output[output_len-1] = 0;`

Then even if they passed me complete garbage, it is at least a valid string.

Answer (score 0):

If the contiguous block of memory that you own starting from `machineMarket` does not have a `\0` then the behaviour of your code is undefined.

Use `strnlen` instead, passing something of the order `VALUE_MARKET_MAX_LEN` as the parameter and then refactor your `>`.